# How can I choose between Shazam and SoundHound?

Tags: applications

I want a Music ID app, I have tried both Shazam and SoundHound which were good. They both have a limit of 5 songs, and cost $5 to upgrade to unlimited. Before purchasing one of them, I want to make sure I'm making the right choice. What are the advantages/disadvantages of each one?

Are there any other competing apps I should consider?

**Update:** I used SoundHound's old name, Midomi, accidentally.

Comment: [Google Sound Search](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.ears) is free of charge.

Answer (score 3):

I would pick a handful of songs that are of the type of music you like and see how each one does at identifying them.  Also consider how long it takes each one to get you your results.  Also if you buy music through a particular service, consider the app's ability to interface easily with that service.  The other big thing to consider would be startup time of the app, since you want to be able to tag a song before it ends!

Answer (score 1):

Both are pretty much the same. I've found that each one sometimes can't identify songs that the other one can.

Both have pretty much the exact same features. SoundHound is a little quicker at recognising the song... it doesn't need that full 10 seconds of the song and will sometimes stop after only 5 seconds of recording.

I'm not 100% sure if Shazam has this but SoundHound also allows you to view the artist and album of the song... i.e. so if you've identified the song, SoundHouse will show you which album that song is from and you can then browse that album right within SoundHound which is pretty good.

I used both but in the end chose to use SoundHound because of the mentioned features above.

Answer (score 0):

I use [SoundHound](http://www.androidcentral.com/android-quick-app-soundhound).  It also costs $5 for the full version.  I can't really articulate why, though; I just liked the interface better.

Answer (score 0):

I've used both and usually Shazam gets me a better result on slower networks. Soundhound has some great extra features. But for long-term, I think I would just use an app like Shazam or Soundhound to find a song I hear, not to share or anything like that.