# Which music-ID app uses less data? Soundhound or Shazam?

Tags: applications, data-connection

I've found **Shazam** and **Soundhound** to be pretty much identical in terms of accuracy when identifying music, however I tried monitoring each app's usage with 3G Watchdog but couldn't get a clear winner between the two, so the question remains:

**Which app uses less data?**

*I looked at the answers for this question: [ [How can I choose between Shazam and SoundHound?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/322/how-can-i-choose-between-shazam-and-soundhound) ], which compares the two, but no information .was provided on data usage.*

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  Are you questioning 3G Watchdog's results?  If so, shouldn't you be asking for a better way to track data usage?

Comment: @Matthew-Read Not really, I'm essentially saying that I think other apps are interfering with the results (other apps might be syncing, etc), so it's hard to "isolate" the apps in question.

Answer (score 1):

Only one way to find out. Recognize 10 songs with each and compare results. No way the data traffic results are the same. You'll need some population (more than 1 tests and take average) in order to get some results.

Ideally you would test with the same data but that is just impossible. Unless you have 2 devices checking the same sound at the exact same time... Still I guess you would be able to make a good comparison with different fragments of the same song on a single device, alternating soundhound and shazam.

What you really want is an app that stores the recorded sound to analyze later on when you're on a free (or at least much cheaper) wifi network. Only reason for this question is you have to watch your data traffic, no?

Comment: "Ideally you would test with the same data but that is just impossible."  You could get fairly close by playing songs from your computer, one time for each app.

Comment: Essentially I ended up using SoundHound (better UI), while blocking it from using mobile data with DroidWall.